# PostgreSQL - Append a table to another and add a field without listing all fields

Tags: postgresql, union, psql

I have two tables:

- `table_a` with fields `item_id`,`rank`, and 50 other fields.
- `table_b` with fields `item_id`, and the same 50 fields as `table_a`

I need to write a SELECT query that adds the rows of `table_b` to `table_a` but with rank set to a specific value, let's say 4.

Currently I have:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a
UNION
SELECT item_id, 4 rank, field_1, field_2, ...
```

How can I join the two tables together without writing out all of the fields and without using an INSERT query?

EDIT:

My idea is to join table_b to table_a somehow with the rank field remaining empty, then simply replace the null rank fields. The rank field is never null, but item_id can be duplicated and table_a may have item_id values that are not in table_b, and vice-versa.

Comment: You have to write out all of the fields. You can hit up `SELECT *
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_schema = 'your_schema'
  AND table_name   = 'your_table'` to get that list and maybe even concatenate a comma to the end of the column names returned from that query so you can just copy/paste in your client.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand why you need this, but you can use [jsonb functions:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
select (jsonb_populate_record(null::table_a, row)).*
from (
    select to_jsonb(a) as row
    from table_a a
    union 
    select to_jsonb(b) || '{"rank": 4}'
    from table_b b
) s
order by item_id;
```

[Working example in rextester.](https://rextester.com/NJIN32266)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure I've got it. The predefined `rank` column can be inserted into `table_b` by joining to the subset of itself with only the columns left of the column behind which you want to insert.

```
WITH
    _leftcols AS ( SELECT item_id, 4 rank FROM table_b ),
    _combined AS ( SELECT * FROM table_b JOIN _leftcols USING (item_id) )
SELECT * FROM _combined
UNION
SELECT * FROM table_a
```